# What is the proper teleport command in Skyrim?

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How does the `coc` command work? When I type in for example `coc Whiterun`, it works. But when I type in `coc Dawnstar`, nothing happens. Did I miss anything here?

Also, how do I enter names with multiple words?

Comment: Why not use the map to fast travel to Whiterun? Does this command work when fast traveling is not possible?

Comment: And it causes no time to pass.

Comment: Well, I'm using it for locations I haven't discovered yet.

Comment: For most console commands, when entering an argument with multiple words, you can use double quotes. e.g. "deadly aim"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two main console commands for quick teleport:

- **coc** (Center-on-Cell) expects one argument (the cell name) and teleports you there. Obviously, "Whiterun" is a cell, while "Dawnstar" isn't. This is for *named* (mostly interior) cells, and expects the name as defined in the Creation Kit. The UESP lists those - where known - as "Console Location Code(s)" in their location descriptions (see: [overview of the Skyrim locations](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Places)).
- **cow** (Center-on-World) expects three arguments: The world name (as defined in the Creation Kit) and the X- and Y-coordinate of the cell in question. Tip for orientation: the highest point in Skyrim is in the worldspace "Tamriel", along with most of Skyrim, at the coordinates 13, -13, so you can get there using `cow Tamriel 13 -13`. The UESP lists those as the *exterior* location coordinates, where known and applicable.

(**Version** 1.1)

Comment: Are you sure you have to reload from an earlier save?  In FO:NV, you just had to save, quit, and reload to re-enable achievements.  Bethesda may have considered that a bug and fixed it with Skyrim, though

Comment: @DaveMcClelland: They "fixed" it.

Comment: Sad news, indeed

Comment: "earlier save" as in, before you entered any console commands?

Comment: @SimonVerbeke: Yes. Potentially even before you *opened* the console, but I couldn't verify it either way. People report slightly different sightings, but it wouldn't be the first time with Bethesda that a bugfix introduces even more strange behaviour ... See the "[Steam Achievements not working?](http://forums.bethsoft.com/index.php?/topic/1262411-steam-achievements-not-working/)" thread on the official forums for all the different problems people have with them.

Comment: @MartinSojka: I can confirm that simply *opening* the console does *not* stop you from getting achievements: I *regularly* open the console on accident and I've gotten plenty of achievements after those times.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Well, at least that one was just a rumour then. :) Anyway, achievements and console are a topic for a different question, I think.

Comment: @MartinSojka I can confirm That `ncl` and `player.additem` do **not** prevent getting an achievement in 1.1.21.0  More detail: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/35162/6914

Comment: Using console **does not** disqualify you from getting Steam achievements in Skyrim.

Answer (score 3):

You can view a complete, searchable list (that is faster and easier to use than UESP) of all the COC cell names in Skyrim [here](http://www.skyrimsearch.com/categories/cells/).

The list also has filters (that combine with the search) according to Skyrim's holds, including all the developer's testing cells.

The site also has easy-to-use lists for NPCs, items, books (including full text of every book) and more, with more searchable lists coming soon.