# What is the best way to fix the Fort Greenwall Bug in the Civil War?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have been tasked with meeting the soldiers and taking over Fort Greenwall. To my surprise, my imperial soldier allies were not at the gathering spot. Furthermore, no stormcloaks were inside the fort either.

As such, I cannot complete the objective "Kill enemies - 100% left", as there are no enemies to kill (except maybe one horse).

I've attempted to wait for 10 in game days, but that did not work.

I have found 3 methods to "fix" this problem.

The first is to go to Riften and defeat the Jarl. A [source](https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/501144-no-one-at-battle-for-fort-greenwall/) tells me this might break the next quest.

The second is to use the  console command

```
setcommand CWFortSiegeFort 9000
```

which will complete the Fort Greenwall quest.

The third is to use the console command

```
resetquest CWFortSiegeFort
```

to [reset](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/208290/can-you-restart-a-quest-from-the-beginning) the fort quest and hopefully make it work again.

I would like to know which, (maybe not among these), is the best solution for fixing this bug?

Comment: The best solution is to load a previous save.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I don't have a recent previous save. I'd have to restart the whole civil war questline.

Comment: I would suggest making a new save, then trying each one out in turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second option (the first console command) is your best bet, as it is the least likely to affect other aspects of the game. However, in doing so you lose the opportunity to get any of the loot from Civ quest Greenwall.