# Stuck in College of Winterhold

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm doing "Find the Arch-Mage," but cannot exit the College of Winterhold. Every time I try to pass through a door marked "Exit to Skyrim," the game crashes. I enabled logging, but nothing is appearing in the logs folder (not even a log file).

Aside from reverting to an earlier save (I was delinquent and don't have any recent ones), is there any fix I can try?

Edit: I run it through Nexus Mod Manager.

Comment: Do you have access to the console?

Comment: @JonK: I'm playing on a PC, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Bit of a blind guess then; do you still crash if you enter `COC Whiterun` in the console?

Comment: Or do you have mods installed? They've been known to cause crashes, too.

Comment: @JonK I tried entering that line and it still crashed.

Comment: @Frank I do have some mods installed: Total Character makeover, unoffical skyrim special edition patch, open cities, wildcat, diverse dragons, animal tweaks, alternate start, cutting room floor, lethal traps, realistic ragdolls and force, run for your lives, sturdy dragons, relationship dialogue overhaul

Comment: That's going to be your problem, I bet. Disable the all, try again. If it works, it's one of your mods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you stated in the comments, you use some mods that could be causing the problem. Disabling them in Nexus Mod Manager could already solve your problem.

If it doesn't, use the [Teleport Command](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36338/what-is-the-proper-teleport-command-in-skyrim) to move your character to another location (with mods still disabled).